# How to set order to Shopify order attributes?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I am creating order attributes like latitude and longitude in Shopify. But sometime their order is interchanged like latitude comes first and longitude second or vice-versa. I just want to set order so that Latitude always comes first. Anyone have idea how to do that. Any guidance will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code from what did you tried so far?

Comment: I have created cart attributes using this url https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/cart/get-more-information-with-cart-attributes and add their value using google geolocation Api

Comment: why does it matter about order of attributes. It is a key:value pair. Your key determines the value. So a key of latitude is just that.

Comment: @DavidLazer, I am sending my order details in zapier and it cause issue there. Thats why I want to set order

Comment: Just like @DavidLazar, said they are key:value pair. If you need control of the attributes you could try to write your own integration with Zapier and you can check the name of the key and set whatever order you want.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can do this using Shopify API but for this, you need two things that are:-

- Product Id
- Collection Id

Using these two Ids you can get 'Collect'. Collect is the relation between a product & collection.

```
$collect_data = GET /admin/collects.json?product_id=1925263361&collectionid=29722105
```

After getting collect data you can get collect id from that data and use collect id you can delete that collect when you delete collect product is automatically removed from the collection. For delete Collect API is:-

```
DELETE /admin/collects/#{collect_id}.json
```

I hope this is helpful for you. Please let me know if you have any query. I am happy to help you.